# What examples do you use to visualize/concretize probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, big-list

When thinking about any mathematical topic, visualizing different specific examples of what I'm studying always helps.

For probability theory, I tend to think in terms of possible universes or stock markets when thinking about time series, apart from the more typical coin flips or dice when its applicable.

I think collecting multiple weird and exotic examples can help ones understanding, so that's why I'm asking the question: **which exotic/weird/noticable examples do you use for thinking about probability theory (and how does it help you)?** (It's ok if the examples are only applicable to very specific domains.)

Comment: When thinking about random variables I tend to think on an abstact sample space which I normally represent as a 2D plane, line or boxes for discrete, and a rapid flickering of points on this space where the flickering density is proportional to the probability. Then I picture it in a very quick movie in my mind

Comment: I use card games (include Magic and YGO), D&D, and waiting for a bus. I also tend to include team and committee formation.